# symfony 1 image style proper way

Tags: css, image, symfony1, styles

What is the most proper way to adapt style on image-tag using symfony framework.
Here is my example:

```
<?php echo link_to(image_tag('/design/fb.png'), 'https://www.facebook.com') ?>
```

How to style fb.png image, for example i wanna use `margin-top: 5px;`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is many options here.

You can see them by checking the `AssetHelper.php` inside symfony:

```
/**
 * Returns an <img> image tag for the asset given as argument.
 *
 * <b>Options:</b>
 * - 'absolute' - to output absolute file paths, useful for embedded images in emails
 * - 'alt'  - defaults to the file name part of the asset (capitalized and without the extension)
 * - 'size' - Supplied as "XxY", so "30x45" becomes width="30" and height="45"
 *
 * <b>Examples:</b>
 * <code>
 *  echo image_tag('foobar');
 *    => <img src="images/foobar.png" alt="Foobar" />
 *  echo image_tag('/my_images/image.gif', array('alt' => 'Alternative text', 'size' => '100x200'));
 *    => <img src="/my_images/image.gif" alt="Alternative text" width="100" height="200" />
 * </code>
 *
 * @param string $source  image asset name
 * @param array  $options additional HTML compliant <img> tag parameters
 *
 * @return string XHTML compliant <img> tag
 * @see    image_path
 */
function image_tag($source, $options = array())
```

So, you can directly integrate the `style` attribute:

```
<?php echo link_to(
    image_tag(
        '/design/fb.png', 
        array('style' => 'margin-top: 5px;')
    ),
    'https://www.facebook.com'
) ?>
```

Or define a `class` as attribute and create the `class` in a css file

```
<?php echo link_to(
    image_tag(
        '/design/fb.png', 
        array('class' => 'img-fb')
    ),
    'https://www.facebook.com'
) ?>
```

And you css:

```
.img-fb {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```